# How to restart systemd service if it is taking too long to run?

Tags: systemd

I have a service that runs a slow and buggy one-shot program once a week that may hang sometimes for no apparent reason. I want this service to be restarted if it took longer than 4 hours to run. I tried to set it up to restart after 4 hours if it is still running with the following unit definition:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some buggy software

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/buggy
ExecStart=/home/buggy/run
Environment=NODE_VERSION=14
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=4 h
StartLimitBurst=4
StartLimitInterval=1 s
```

And a timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some buggy software schedule timer

[Timer]
Unit=buggy.service
OnCalendar=Sat *-*-* 22:00:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

But it still can hang indefinitely, I came to see my service two days after it run and it was still hung.

What did I do wrong? Is there even a way to do what I need with systemd?

Comment: Am I right to assume that /home/buggy/run does not `fork()` into the background, but blocks until completed?

Comment: In that case, you'd want your Serice to have `Type=oneshot`, and/or probably use `TimeoutSec=`

Answer (score 1):

Use the RuntimeMaxSec directive. You cannot use a watchdog because buggy program will need to be modified.

From [`man systemd.service`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.service.5.html):

> `RuntimeMaxSec=`
>
> Configures a maximum time for the service to run. If this is used and the service has been active for longer than the specified time it is terminated and put into a failure state. Note that this setting does not have any effect on `Type=oneshot` services, as they terminate immediately after  activation completed. Pass `infinity` (the default) to configure no runtime limit.
>
> If a service of `Type=notify`/`Type=notify-reload` sends `EXTEND_TIMEOUT_USEC=...`, this may cause the runtime to be extended beyond `RuntimeMaxSec=`. The first receipt of this message must occur before `RuntimeMaxSec=` is exceeded, and once the runtime has extended beyond `RuntimeMaxSec=`, the service manager will allow the service to continue to run, provided the service repeats `EXTEND_TIMEOUT_USEC=...` within the interval specified until the service shutdown is achieved by `STOPPING=1` (or termination). (see
> `sd_notify(3)`).